Text formatting inside a paragraph acting like a numbered list
For markdown files and the like, I have formatoptions set to tln and I am using a simplified version of formatlistpat that looks for digits and a * character. The indenting on a list works fine, the way I expect it to.
But, when I have a paragraph with numbers in it, where the auto-wrap causes the line to start with a numeric, it is acting like that line is a numbered list and indents the following line.
Example:
When you are writing code in Python
3.12, you need to ensure that you
   are using the latest version.

This drives me crazy enough that I have a function to quickly turn formatting on and off. Is there a better way to detect what is and isn't a list? Some way to say if the list section doesn't have a blank leading line it isn't a list? A way of invoking Q} two different ways, with and without list formatting?
Any tips / configuration help would be greatly appreciated.

I don't understand the Q} thing. Did you mean gq}?

Maybe could you share your formatlistpat and a small text just to verify that the solution proposed solves your problem.

Sorry, yes gq}, I have a nnoremap on Q which I've had for so long I forget that everyone else doesn't. Not sure where I picked that up
Current settings that may be relevant:
autoindent
textwidth=78
formatoptions=tcql
filetype=ghmarkdown
formatlistpat=^\s*[0-9*]\+[\]:.)}\t ]\s*

I would suggest:
set autoindent
set indentexpr=

I suspect that indentexpr is automatically set to GetMarkdownIndent() that add the indentation you don't want.
The pattern I have used is:
set formatlistpat=^\\s*\\(\\d\\+[.)]\\\|\\*\\)\\s 

or
let &formatlistpat='^\s*\(\d\+[.)]|\*\)\s'

This to accept:
  * bullet1
  * bullet2

or
  1. bullet1
  2. bullet2

But not:
  3.12, foo
  3.1 bar

Remark: tested with:
set formatoptions=tln
set autoindent
set indentexpr=
set textwidth=80


Thanks @vivian-de-smedt it looks like it comes down to the formatlistpat, if I'm reading it correctly yours requires a numeric list to have a delimiter (period, bracket, etc) whereas mine allows blank. This means any number for me at the start of a line is getting interpreted as a list, whereas yours requires the number and the delimiter.
Thanks for this, you've made my day!

Thanks for the feedback :-) I'm happy your problem is solved. Welcome to Vim!
